# Последовательность диалогов Telegram

Tags: python, telegram

Как я могу реализовать диалог с ботом? (должна быть последовательность)

К примеру, при вводе `/start`, бот выводит: " выбор: x или y", показывается клавиатура с x и y. Когда человек нажимает x, должны выполняться какие-то действия, при нажатии y - другие.  после этого он уже не должен написать y, и инициировать выполнение уже других действий. ЛИБО X, ЛИБО Y. Чтобы выбрать y, надо писать заново `/start`. Проверяю входящие сообщения так:

```
if text == '/start':
  bot.sendMessage(author, strings.starts)
  show_keyboard = {'keyboard': [["x", "y"], ["z"]]}
  bot.sendMessage(author, 'Please, choose', reply_markup=show_keyboard)
if text == 'y':
*some actions*
```

нужна последовательность. помогите, пожалуйста.
желательно, с примерам

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 4):

Вот мой вариант

```
import telebot #pyTelegramBotAPI
from telebot import types
import shelve
bot = telebot.TeleBot('token')
@bot.message_handler(command=['start'])
def start(mess):
    chat_id = mess.chat.id
    storage = shelve.open('shelve')
    storage[str(chat_id)] = 'init'
    storage.close()
    markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup()
    btn_x = types.KeyboardButton('x')
    btn_y = types.KeyboardButton('y')
    markup.add(btn_x, btn_y)
    bot.send_message(chat_id, 'x или y', reply_markup=markup)
@bot.message_handler(func=lambda mess: mess.text == 'y' and mess.content_type == 'text')
def y(mess):
    chat_id = mess.chat.id
    storage = shelve.open('shelve')
    state = storage[str(chat_id)]
    if state != 'init':
        pass
        storage.close()
    else:
        storage[str(chat_id)] = 'y'
        storage.close()
        #твой код
@bot.message_handler(func=lambda mess: mess.text == 'x' and mess.content_type == 'text')
def x(mess):
    chat_id = mess.chat.id
    storage = shelve.open('shelve')
    state = storage[str(chat_id)]
    if state != 'init':
        pass
        storage.close()
    else:  
        storage[str(chat_id)] = 'y'
        storage.close()
        #твой код
if __name__ == '__main__':
    bot.polling(True)
```